# Page not found (404) jquery django python

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-templates, django-static

jquery does not load - Page not found (404)

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'bootstrap-5.0.0/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
 </head>
```

**setting.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ServiceCRM3/static'),]
```

- static folder created
- the script is in the path static / jquery / jquery.js
- bootstrap picks up ok in the same folder
- the server restarted

what's wrong?

Comment: have you called '**collectstatic**

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: i need put my file in STATICFILES_DIRS, not  in STATIC_URL